# Java: isFullScreenSupported returns true, but setFullScreenWindow is simulated?

Tags: java, swing, awt, screen, fullscreen

I'm doing some heavy graphics work, and I wanted to try out full screen mode. The graphics device claims that full screen is supported, but when I consequently set the full screen window, the window appears in simulated full screen mode.

```
    GraphicsDevice gd = graph.getDevice();
    if(gd.isFullScreenSupported()){
            //gd.setFullScreenWindow(null);
            gd.setFullScreenWindow(window);
    }
```

Below is a screen shot of the resulting "full screen" display. I have not told the window to resize the image, nor to display "on top", but these should be independent issues. Is this actually the expected behavior?

[image: Full screen bug example]

Comment: What exactly consuses you here? default window header?

Comment: Yeah - the task bar is visible, the top and sides of the window are visible... I expected full screen mode to replace the entire contents of the screen with the contents of the window. Is the function of this process to use the window's paint method, therefore including the top bar and task bar and everything?

Comment: Removing the top and sides is quite simple: window.setUndecorated(true)

Comment: This is a little "misleading".  While it might seem reasonable to pass the API a `JFrame`, if you read the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/exclusivemode.html), they actually use a `JWindow`